# Query Results across 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a need to see a client was billed for a specific item.  The tables are as follows Client, Orders, Details.  The way they connect is Client to Orders and Orders to Details.  (client.acctno = order.acctno, order.orderno = details.orderno)

How can I search all orders and display only those that have not been sold a specific item (sample code with exact table names below).  My data keep showing all clients because they weren't sold the items a specific order I want to bunch them all together as ALL ORDERS and compare.

```
SELECT * 
FROM plshared.dbo.client 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PL00.dbo.ordhdr ON ordhdr.ACCT_NO = client.ACCT_NO
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM pl00.dbo.orddet
                  WHERE orddet.ORDER_NO = ordhdr.order_no 
                    AND orddet.ITEM_NO = '2017WI') 
 --GROUP BY client.ACCT_NO
 ORDER BY CLIENT.ACCT_NO
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: SQL Server Mgnt Studio

Comment: So then please add a `sql-server` tag to your question ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your query is at the order level.  You might find it easier to get the clients by doing:

```
SELECT o.ACCT_NO
FROM PL00.dbo.ordhdr o JOIN
     pl00.dbo.orddet od
     ON od.ORDER_NO = o.order_no 
GROUP BY o.ACCT_NO
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN od.ITEM_NO = '2017WI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
ORDER BY o.ACCT_NO;
```